# Parsing json returned in django modelformset in template

Tags: django, django-templates, formset

One of the fields returned to my template in a formset generated by modelformset_factory() is a JSONField. I'd like to parse the json and display elements in it separately within the form, read-only.

This is readily done if I just return the queryset list, using a builtin filter I created, get(). But it has to be in a form that has some added fields for users to fill.

```
{% for foo in foo_list %}
  <h5>{{ foo.json|get:"title" }}</h5>
{% endfor %}
```

The problem is that doing the same for a formset field I get the error "'BoundField' object has no attribute 'get'"

```
{% for form in formset %}
  <h5>{{ form.json|get:"title" }}</h5>
{% endfor %}
```

Here is the filter:

```
@register.filter(name='get')
def get(d, k):
    print('get(d,k):',d,k)
    return d.get(k, None)
```

The relevant bits of the view:

```
...
foo_list = Foo.objects.all()
...
FooFormset = modelformset_factory(
    Foo, fields = ['task_id','authority','dataset','place_id',
        'authrecord_id','json'], form=FooModelForm, extra=0)
formset = FooFormset(request.POST or None, queryset=foo_list)
context['formset'] = formset
...
return render(request, 'datasets/review.html', context=context)
```

Comment: But this doesn't make sense. `foo` is a form, and `foo.json` is a field: it's a place for you to enter JSON in string format. It isn't actually JSON itself. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I was not clear; `foo` is in the first case an element in `foo_list` and `foo.json` is a json object. But that first bit doesn't involve forms. The problem is what follows -  rendering the value of a BoundField in a template. I found the answer in an old patch thread - BoundField.value, described in my self-answer below. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found that applying a custom filter to form.json.value did the trick. The new filter converts that (text) value to json, from which I can do a get for specific keys.

new get filter:

```
@register.filter(name='get')
def get(d, k):
    jd = json.loads(d)
    return jd.get(k, None)
```

and its implementation in a template:

```
{{ form.json.value|get:"names" }}
```

BoundField.value is text, even though json in the db, so it needs conversion back for parsing.